# Suddenly can't add comments... "3 more to go..."

Tags: support, questions, comments

I suddenly can't add comments, but get a message "3 more to go...".

I'm trying to comment on an answer to my question. I've never seen this before. What is it?

I tried changing browsers, but get the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you entered at least 15 characters? 3 more to go means you need to type 3 more characters to satisfy the 15 character minimum requirement.

Comment: Just like it states "enter at least 15 characters" below the comment box when starting, and then shows a countdown while typing. Doesn't that show in your browser, @IanC?

Comment: @Arjan It changes to "X more to go" once you start typing, so it's fairly non-obvious if you didn't notice the "enter at least 15 characters" before you started typing

Comment: Odd, it's not some hidden tooltip, and especially the change from "enter at least 15 characters" into the much shorter countdown is very visible on my computer (Safari on a MacBook), @Michael. So, I'm still wondering if some browsers might actually not show this at all? (But then: IanC also changed browsers, so I guess it's just not too visible on some screens then?)

Comment: To be honest, the problem is I wasn't looking at that part of the screen. I think too many late nights caught up with me. So my blonde error for the month ;) thanks guys

Comment: I just ran into this and I thought it meant 3 more comments to go, not 3 more characters. Bad error message.